# Payment to this merchant is not allowed in android while integrating paypal

Tags: android, paypal

I am using sandbox account and following the tutorial http://androiddevelopmentanddiscussion.blogspot.com/2014/05/paypal-integration-in-android.html

I have given the client id which i have achieved by logging into sandbox account from my selling tools->api access

Here is my code:

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;

    // note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
            // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
            .merchantName(" ")
            .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
            .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));

    PayPalPayment thingToBuy;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);

    }


    public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
        // PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE will cause the payment to complete immediately.
        // Change PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE to PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE to only authorize payment and 
        // capture funds later.


        if(pressed.getId() == R.id.button1){
            thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("8"), "USD", "Painting 1", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        }else if(pressed.getId() == R.id.button2){
            thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("4"), "USD", "Painting 2", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        }



        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
    }

    public void onFuturePaymentPressed(View pressed) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.class);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(TAG,"An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PayPalAuthorization auth =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                if (auth != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", auth.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                        String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", authorization_code);

                        sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Future Payment code received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("FuturePaymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        "FuturePaymentExample",
                        "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendAuthorizationToServer(PayPalAuthorization authorization) {

    }

    public void onFuturePaymentPurchasePressed(View pressed) {
        // Get the Application Correlation ID from the SDK
        String correlationId = PayPalConfiguration.getApplicationCorrelationId(this);

        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "Application Correlation ID: " + correlationId);

        // TODO: Send correlationId and transaction details to your server for processing with
        // PayPal...
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(), "App Correlation ID received from SDK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Stop service when done
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Here is the log message:

```
01-12 06:32:04.143: E/paypal.sdk(1778): request failure with http statusCode:401,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
01-12 06:32:04.143: E/paypal.sdk(1778): request failed with server response:{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}
01-12 06:32:04.143: E/PayPalService(1778): invalid_client
```

I am new in this topic so explanation would be nice.

Comment: check you paypal credentials

Comment: and how would i do that??

Comment: private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = ""; put your client id here. empty key will take you nowhere..

Comment: i have a id, to post in here i have made it blank. plz check if the way of my key collection from sandbox is correct or not??

Comment: what credentials you are using  ? did you create your sandbox credentials ?

Comment: yes i have created!! but it's showing invalid merchant

Comment: check this link https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Use your sandbox credential (Client id) here.

```
private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "";
```

Or follow below links:

[Paypal integration using SDK](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/paypal-sdk-integration-in-android-applications/)

[Paypal integration using gradle integration](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-paypal-integration-tutorial/)